# Connectedness of disjoint union

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topological space $Z$ defined as the disjoint union $Z=X\cup Y$. Please tell me if these statements are true:

1) If both $X$ and $Y$ are open in $Z$ or both are closed in $Z$ then $Z$ must be disconnected

2) If one of them is open and the other is closed then $Z$ may or may not be connected. For example $\{0\}$ is closed in $[0,1]$ and $(0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$ but $\{0\}\cup (0,1]=[0,1]$ is connected. The second example, take $Z=(0,1)\cup [2,3]$ then $(0,1)$ is open in $Z$ and $[2,3]$ is closed in $Z$ but $Z$ is not connected. Thanks alot.

Comment: If $Z$ is disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$ then $X$ and $Y$ are _both closed and open_ in $Z$.

Comment: are you saying that $\{0\}$ and $(0,1]$ are both open in $[0,1]$?

Comment: I misunderstood. What I said above is true if you endow $Z$ with the disjoint union topology of $X$ and $Y$, that is, if you start from $X$ and $Y$ and define $Z= X \coprod Y$ with the disjoint union topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is correct, pretty much by definition, assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are non-empty.
2. This is also true. Note, however, that in $(0,1)\cup[2,3]$, the sets $(0,1)$ and $[2,3]$ are both open and both closed: it’s not like your first example, in which $\{0\}$ is closed but not open, and $(0,1]$ is open but not closed.

Comment: I'm sorry i meant to write "must be disconnected" instead of "must be connected". If you don't mind, i will correct it in my question.

Comment: @palio: By all means, and I’ll revise my answer accordingly.

Comment: would you please tell me the intuition behind the connectedness of $Z$ being dependent on subsets $X$ and $Y$ being open or closed, knowing that connectedness as compactness are intrinsic properties of the space which does not depend on the topology we define on the space.

Comment: @palio: I’m not sure what you mean: connectedness and compactness both depend entirely on the topology of the space. But they are intrinsic properties of the space in the sense that they *don’t* depend on how it’s embedded in some other space.

Comment: @palio: "connectedness as compactness are intrinsic properties of the space which does not depend on the topology" is **just patently false**. Every space admits both the [discrete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space) and [indiscrete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) topologies. The latter is always connected, the former is always disconnected if the space has at least 2 points.

Comment: i see what you mean.. i was thinking geometrically a connected space is "one piece" space.. a circle will always be a "connected= one piece" circle no matter what the topology we put on it.

Comment: @palio: That’s not true: we can endow any set with the discrete topology, making it totally disconnected.